# Почему не работают методы после открытия ServiceHost?

Tags: c#, wcf, hosting

Пишу сервис. Задача которого: оповещение клиентов о обновлении.
Вот контракти:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientCallBackContract))]
public interface IBHDashBoardContract
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]    
    void RegisterClient();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UnRegisterClient();
}
```

Контракт который реализует клиент:

```
public interface IClientCallBackContract
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UpdateAqua(DataSet AquaDS);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UpdateCalls(DataSet CallsDS);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UpdateCooler(DataSet CoolerDS);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UpdateDriver(DataSet DriverDS);
}
```

Реализация:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class BHDashBoardService : IBHDashBoardContract
{
    static List<Client> _clients = new List<Client>();

    public object Dataset { get; private set; }

    public void RegisterClient()
    {
        var client = new Client()
        {
            ClientId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallBackContract>()
        };
        _clients.Add(client);

        Console.WriteLine("Registered :" + client.ClientId);
    }

    public void UnRegisterClient()
    {
        var _callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallBackContract>();

        Console.WriteLine("UnRegistered :" + _clients.First(c => c.Callback == _callback));

        _clients.RemoveAll(c => c.Callback == _callback);

    }

    public BHDashBoardService()
    {
        int msToUpdate = 10000;
        int msToStart = 1000;
        Timer timerAqua = new Timer(UpdateAquaMenu, null, msToStart, msToUpdate);
        Timer timerCalls = new Timer(UpdateCalls, null, msToStart, msToUpdate);
        Timer timerCoolers = new Timer(UpdateCoolerMenu, null, msToStart, msToUpdate);
    }

    ~BHDashBoardService()
    {

    }

    void UpdateAquaMenu(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UpdateAqua: " + DateTime.Now);

        //creating and fill dataset;
        DataSet _aquaDS = null;

        foreach (var client in _clients)
            client.Callback.UpdateAqua(_aquaDS); // send to client new dataset
    }

    void UpdateCalls(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UpdateCalls: " + DateTime.Now);

        //creating and fill dataset;
        DataSet _aquaDS = null;

        foreach (var client in _clients)
            client.Callback.UpdateCalls(_aquaDS); // send to client new dataset
    }

    void UpdateCoolerMenu(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UpdateCoolers: " + DateTime.Now);

        //creating and fill dataset;
        DataSet _aquaDS = null;

        foreach (var client in _clients)
            client.Callback.UpdateCooler(_aquaDS); // send to client new dataset
    }
}
```

Клиент:

```
public class Client
{
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }

    public IClientCallBackContract Callback { get; set; }

}
```

Сам хост:

```
Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:4000/IBHDashBoardContract");

WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();

ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(BHDashBoardService));

Console.WriteLine("Host created");
Console.ReadKey();

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IBHDashBoardContract), binding, address);

host.Open();

Console.WriteLine("Host Opened");

Console.ReadKey();

host.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Host Closed");
```

Почему до открытия хоста методы update исполняются каждые 10 секунд, а после открытия перестают исполняться.

[image: Пример запуска хоста]

Подключить клиента к не открытому хосту я не смогу. А нужно чтобы и методы работали и хост был включен. Помогите!

Comment: А в чем проблема этого??? Я подключал пользователей. Выводилось сообщении о регистрации.         Console.WriteLine("Registered :" + client.ClientId); 
Да и до открытия тоже стоить ReadKey() и все работает

Comment: А, все проще. Ваши таймеры собрал сборщик мусора.

Comment: Щас попробую объявить таймеры в самом класе. Тогда не должен собрать.

Comment: Сработало. Я дурак. Забыл о Garbage Collector.... Он сразу все удалял. Минус c#... Я думал он будет удалять не сразу когда пропала ссылка на объект, а когда ему недостаточно памяти тогда он просто делает Collect... Могу поставить плюсик. Напишите в ответ.